# Access entire row during Kendo DataSource custom filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I'm trying to apply custom filter to Kendo DataSource so that it filters using calculation of a few columns.
E.g. filter all items that has field1 value greater than filterValue percent of field2 value.

```
dataSource.filter({
    field: 'field1',
    operator: function(value) {
        return value * 100 / valueFromField2 > filterValue;
    },
    value: filterValue
})
```

So basically I need to get an access to other row fields from within a operator function.

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to apply it to your case, but if you want to access other rows in a Kendo Grid, you can:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); // The complete grid
var row = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(0)"); // Row index. Starts from 0. Excludes header row
var data = grid.dataItem(row); // 'data' now has all fields for 'row'
```

Consider an example grid:

```
column1|column2
---------------
----1--|--One--
----2--|--Two--
---------------
```

Hence, for `eq(0)`:

```
data.column1: 1
data.column2: One
```

More information: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-tbody

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm afraid I can't use this solution since I don't know row index during filtering and extracting rows on every filter method call should hit performance especially for big data set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to iterate each field value.

Something like:

```
function (value) {

        var rowData = this.dataSource.view();

        for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) { // Iterate each row
            $.each(rowData[i].items, function (index, object) { // Iterate each object
                var uid = object.uid;

                // DO YOUR LOGIC HERE

            });
        }
    }
```